# PHP Searching MYSQL Database For Variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hi im trying to create my own simple log in system. i conect to the mysql server and now want to find if the username is in the Users chart i created on the mysql database. if it is let them through to the members area. how exactly would i do this?

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "mysql14.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a6981734_Users";
$mysql_user = "XXXXX";
$mysql_password = "XXXXX";
$account = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $account);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $account);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username1 = $row['Username'];
    if($username1 == $username) {
        echo "Welcome";
        break;

    } else {
        echo "Username / Password Not Found In Database";
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

HTML LOGIN FORM!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="PHPVALIDATE.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Where` to your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$username."' AND Password='".$password."'";
//Assuming your column name is Password to store your password.
```

**Additional Note** Learn `mysqli` or `PDO` As `mysql` is depriciated.

**Updated Answer**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$mysql_host = "mysql14.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a6981734_Users";
$mysql_user = "XXXXX";
$mysql_password = "XXXXX";
$account = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $account);




    $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo $username.'<br/>';
echo $password.'<br/>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$username."' AND Password='".$password."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $account) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username1 = $row['Username'];
    $password1=$row['Password'];
    echo $username1.'<br/>';
    echo $password1.'<br/>';
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: it just echos out what you inputed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $account);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows>0){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username1 = $row['username'];
    $password1= $row['password'];

     $username1=$_SESSION['username'];
     header("location:member_page?u='.$username1.'");

} else {
 echo "Username / Password Not Found In Database";

  }
 }
}
```

header() would redirect users to the area(page),you want them to send.

Hope that helps.Let me know that works or not

Comment: it doesn't work and i get this error. Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in /home/a6981734/public_html/MYSQLRegister/PHPVALIDATE.php on line 26

Comment: remove the break from else statement.You don't even need it.Let me know what happens

Comment: and remember Username is different from username.Mysql is case-sensetive.